# Instructing Sphinx to use a specific version of Python

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've got a project that can only run with the `32-bit` build of `Python 2.7`. Unfortunately my `Sphinx` build insists on using the `64-bit` build. I've spent the best part of three hours trying to build `Sphinx` so that when I use the `sphinx-quickstart` utility it will run with my `32-bit` `python`. The last thing I tried was altering the `Sphinx` `makefile`, replacing every occurrence of `$(PYTHON)` with the path to my `32-bit` `python`. For example:

```
build:
    @$(PYTHON) setup.py build
```

became

```
build:
    @python2.7-32 setup.py build
```

I then ran

```
~/Downloads/Sphinx-1.2b1 make
~/Downloads/Sphinx-1.2b1 python2.7-32 setup.py install
```

The build went okay, but Sphinx still insists on using the 'wrong' version of `python`.
I've given up hope of solving this one on my own, and am looking for a bit of guidance.

Many thanks

Comment: When building Sphinx, you could've just set the python variable to avoid changing every occurrence, i.e. `PYTHON=python2.7-32`.

Comment: I did this also, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Well, you could always make a shell alias. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `virtualenv --python=PYTHON_EXE` to create a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) with your preferred version of Python. This will ensure that the packages you install will run against your preferred version of Python.